# Create Associative Array using For Loop

Tags: php, arrays

I want an array in the below format using Variables stored from the database and $_GET

```
array('FNAME' => 'NIDHI','EMAIL' => 'example@email.com','SRC' => '')
```

What I am trying is like below

```
if ($variableResult->num_rows>0) {
            
            while($variable_row = $variableResult->fetch_assoc()) {

              $variableArray[] = $variable_row['variable_name'];
              
            }
            
            $totalVariables = count($variableArray);
            
            
         
            for($i = 0; $i < $totalVariables; $i++) {
              
              $dataArray[] = array($variableArray[$i] => htmlspecialchars($_GET[$variableArray[$i]]));
              
            }

            var_dump($dataArray);
            exit();
            
        }
```

It's giving me output like below

> array(5) { [0]=> array(1) { ["EMAIL"]=> string(17) "nidhi@example.com"
> } [1]=> array(1) { ["LNAME"]=> string(5) "NIDHI" } [2]=> array(1) {
> ["THIS_IS_CUSTOM"]=> string(0) "" } [3]=> array(1) {
> ["THIS_IS_CUSTOM_2"]=> string(0) "" } [4]=> array(1) {
> ["THIS_IS_CUSTOM_3"]=> string(0) "" } }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need two loops here. 1) while and 2) for. While is enough.

Note: The below code may not perfect. You may need to change it a little bit :)

```
$variableArray = []; // declare blank array variable first
while($variable_row = $variableResult->fetch_assoc()) { 
   if(!empty($variable_row['variable_name'])){ // check if key presnt
       $varName = $variable_row['variable_name'];
       if(!empty($_GET[$varName])){ // check if valid get variable exist
            $variableArray[$varName] = htmlspecialchars($_GET[$varName]); 
       }
   }  
}
// print it for better visibility
echo '<pre>'; print_r($variableArray); echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's giving you the correct result but the formatting is a bit confusing.

Replace:

```
var_dump($dataArray);
```

with:

```
print("<pre>".print_r($dataArray,true)."</pre>");
```

Comment: Hi Manny! Thanks for your answer but its giving another array inside array Like this https://prnt.sc/1aeomgb Which I do not want, I want single array as I have asked in my question. Thanks!

Comment: Would you post the output